# 404 Error page is not being found

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic

I have following controller, which I can access directly from browser, no problem, behaves as expected:

```
@RequestMapping("/error404")
public String errorController() {
    return "my-error";
}
```

in `web.xml` I have the following:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404</location>
</error-page>
```

however, if I try to load any non-existing page (so 404 error is generated by server), I'm getting following:

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101305> <[ServletContext@13590558[app:_appsdir_Manage_dir module:/myapp path:/myapp spec-version:2.5]] Error-page location: "/error404" for the error-code: "404" causes an infinite loop condition as it throws the same code for which it has been mapped.>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I really don't know where to look, and why is this occurs.

spring 3.2

Comment: whats the exact url you are using when accessing error controller directly from browser ?

Comment: localhost/myapp/error404

Answer (score 0):

If you dont do any actions in your "/error404" method try to comment this method and insert into spring configuration:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/error404" view-name="my-error" />
```

Comment: actually I do, I just removed the code, as it seemed irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We finally solved the issue with adding a DefaultHandler, that is called when no mapping is found.

A stripped down example below, assuming that you use JavaConfig.

The initial Spring-MVC setup:

```
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class BaseWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
  @Inject
  private NoMappingFoundHandler noMappingFoundHandler;
  ...

  @Override
  @Bean
  public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping()
  {
    final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setDefaultHandler(noMappingFoundHandler);
    return handlerMapping;
  }
}
```

The handler:

```
@Component
public class NoMappingFoundHandler extends DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler
{
  @Override
  public void handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    // NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException throws a "404-Exception", 
    // that is caught by an exception-resolver in our case.
    // Feel free to do whatever you like
    throw new NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException(request);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.